# weblogic change datasource at runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic, datasource

- How do I change weblogic datasource at runtime?
- For example.
  currently it is referring to UAT database Now I want to point to Dev
  database. I know it can be modified in console. I don't want to use
  that method. it requires too much user interaction.
- Any other easy method. 
  Can I modify the datasource in my app config file persistence.xml file to chg form UATdb to DevDb.
- Does it require restarting my weblogic web server?
- How to manage without restarting web server
- Or should I have another web server instance? for UATdb and another for Devdb

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify datasources in your web.xml. JDBC is a weblogic feature. That being said, you can change the datasource info using WLST.

An example of the process is mentioned here.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13737/config.htm#JDBCA134

You can get creative with this process and create and destroy JDBC's based on environment as well.

So long answer short, WLST is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Update data account password

```
connect('weblogic', 'password', 't3://%s:%s' % ('localhost','7001'))
edit()
startEdit()
cd('/')
cd('JDBCSystemResources/dbname/JDBCResource/dbname/JDBCDriverParams/dbname/Properties/dbname/Properties/user')
cmo.setValue('ESB')
cd('/')
cd('JDBCSystemResources/dbname/JDBCResource/dbname/JDBCDriverParams/dbname')
cmo.setPassword('ESB')
cd('/')
save()
activate(block='true')
disconnect()
exit()
```